# Atom + linter-clang

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to run linter-clang in Atom on some C++ files is running into trouble because it can't find the header files.

I notice that in [Dirk's Atom Settings](https://gist.github.com/dirk-thomas/45a47f4de7f2e6d6f18d) that he plugged at ROSCon, there are many ROS header include folders listed manually as part of the settings for `clangIncludePaths`.

What are the appropriate directories to list here, given that I'm using ROS 1.0/indigo and catkin-tools?

@Dirk Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260886/atom-+-linter-clang/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Listing `/opt/ros/indigo/include` should be sufficient to get the system installed ROS packages (see the Kinetic line my config: https://gist.github.com/dirk-thomas/45a47f4de7f2e6d6f18d#file-settings-json-L224).

Additionally you want the include folders from your workspace(s). Depending on how you build your workspace(s) that might become more effort. If you always install into a single location (merged install space). you just add that one too: e.g. `~/ws/install/include`. If you install into package specific paths you will need to enumerate them all, e.g.:

- `~/ws/install/pkgA/include`
- `~/ws/install/pkgB/include`
- ...

And in the case you don't install at all you will have to specify potentially two paths for each package: one pointing to the include folder in the source space and another pointing to the include folder in the devel space.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3